# R Representing state probabilities in a vioplot

Tags: r

I have a vioplot showing three states:

```
library(vioplot)
state1 <- rnorm(100,5,2)
state2  <- rnorm(100,8,3)
state3 <- rnorm(100,12,0.5)
vioplot(state1,state2, state3, names=c("a", "b", "c"), col="green")
```

how can I add to this plot to show graphically
that the probability of state1 occurring is 0.3,
 state2 is 0.2 and  state3 is 0.5 ?

Or is there a better way to represent this graphically?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way to make the width proportional to the probability (perhaps too clever?), but I'm pretty sure `vioplot` won't do that without some hacking, and I couldn't figure out how to induce `ggplot2::geom_violing()` to do it (although it may be possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example (I believe) of Ben Bolker's suggestion to weight the areas of the density estimates according to the given state probabilities. I used the weights argument to ggplot2 to do this, it appears some hacking will be needed to allow the `vioplot` function to allow a weight function (although that would be useful, see [related discussion on crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13555/how-to-scale-violin-plots-for-comparisons)).

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

state1 <- rnorm(100,5,2)
state2  <- rnorm(100,8,3)
state3 <- rnorm(100,12,0.5)
state1_w <- rep(0.3, 100)
state2_w <- rep(0.2, 100)
state3_w <- rep(0.5, 100)

state_df1 <- data.frame(cbind(state1,state2,state3))
state_df2 <- data.frame(cbind(state1_w,state2_w,state3_w))
#now to reshape and merge
state_melt1 <- melt(state_df1, measure.vars = c("state1","state2","state3"), variable.name = "State_Num", value.name = "State_Value")
state_melt2 <- melt(state_df2, measure.vars = c("state1_w","state2_w","state3_w"), variable.name = "State_W", value.name = "State_WValue")
state_melt <- data.frame(state_melt1,state_melt2)

#now making the plot
p1 <- ggplot(data = state_melt, aes(State_Num,State_Value,weight = State_WValue))
p1 + geom_violin(fill = "green")
```

You will get a few error messages saying the weights don't add to one, but here we want the areas to be proportional to their state space probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

```
  text(x=(1:3)+.2, y=-0.5, 
      labels=paste0( "prob=\n", 
                    round( sapply(list(state1, state2, state3), mean)/
                                      length(c(state1, state2, state3)) 
                           ,2) ) )
```