# Violin Plot (geom_violin) with aggregated values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create violin plots with aggregated data. My data has a category, a value coloumn and a count coloumn:

```
data <- data.frame(category = rep(LETTERS[1:3],3),
                   value = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                   count = c(3,2,1,1,2,3,2,1,3))
```

If I create a simple violin plot it looks like this:

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = category, y = value)) + geom_violin()
plot
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [ahschulz.de](http://www.ahschulz.de/pub/overflow/violin_plot.png))</sub>

That is not what I wanted. A solution would be to reshape the dataframe by multiplying the rows of each category-value combination. The problem is that my counts go up to millions which takes hours to be plotted! :-(

Is there a solution with my data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can submit a weight when calculating the areas.

```
plot2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = category, y = value, weight = count)) + geom_violin()
plot2
```

You will get warning messages that the weights do not add to one, but that is ok. See [here for similar/related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605666/604456).

[image]

Comment: this seems to give inaccurate densities. when I plot using this method and compare against plotting with the entire dataset, the plots looks very different

Answer (score 2):

Using `stat="identity"` and specifying a `violinwidth` aesthetic appears to work,although I had to put in a fudge factor:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = category, y = value)) + 
   geom_violin(stat="identity",aes(violinwidth=0.2*count))
```

Comment: Neat solution, this appears to not calculate the KDE at all, but just connect the counts (with the fudge factor to give some gurth?) This may be desirable in some circumstances.

Comment: Yes.  I think your solution is what the OP actually wanted.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for newer versions of ggplot? If I use this code in version 2.1.0, I get `Error: Unknown parameters: trim, scale`.

Comment: don't know.  maybe ask a new question?  I wasn't able to find a solution in a minute or two.

Comment: I asked a question here about the issues I'm having with `count`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847367/ggplot2-violin-plot-with-stat-identity