# ggplot2: Violin Plot with Stat="Identity"

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, violin-plot

I'm trying to use `ggplot` to create a violin plot where instead of the widths of the violins being controlled by a density function, they directly represent the count of relevant elements.

I think this can be accomplished through setting `geom_violin(stat="identity")`, but R then complains

```
> ggplot(allData, aes(x = tool, y = length)) + geom_violin(stat="identity")
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: trim, scale
Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'violinwidth' not found
```

Trying to add `aes(violinwidth=0.2*count)`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16398834/2809263) suggests, gives

```
> ggplot(allData, aes(x = tool, y = length)) + geom_violin(stat="identity", aes(violinwidth=0.2*count))
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: trim, scale
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: violinwidth
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'count' not found
```

And while I can set `violinwidth` to just a constant, this makes the violins just rectangles. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run this with some sample data, it generates the plots ok with and without the changes to `stat` and `violinwidth`. Is your `count` a column in `allData`?

```
library(ggplot2)

dt <- data.frame(category = rep(letters[1:2], each = 10),
                 response = runif(20),
                 count = rpois(20, 5))

ggplot(dt, aes(x = category, y = response)) + geom_violin()

ggplot(dt, aes(x = category, y = response)) + 
  geom_violin(stat = "identity", aes(violinwidth = 0.1*count))
```

Comment: Ah. It does not. I thought I could use `count` without having a `count` column, kinda like how you can do `geom_violin(scale="count")` and it calculates the counts for you

Comment: Yup, adding a `count` column fixed it.

Comment: `Ignoring unknown aesthetics: violinwidth`

Comment: Strange warning, it does seem to be controlling the width still e.g. if you change it to 0.2* it does grow